# Limit getRange to a specific Sheet not working with onEdit function

Tags: javascript, for-loop, google-sheets

When I'm on sheet Novo Item:
I've got this piece of script to work and its goal is to generate a unique ID once cell W4 changes on sheet Novo Item. It iterates through a list of ID on another sheet (ArquivoItens) and adds 1 to it, if the ID doesn't exist there yet.

I have also set a n alert msg, in case the user writes a product name name that already exists in ArquivoItens.

When I'm on sheet EditarItem and when I change the value of cell W4, the alert message even though I had specified the sheet name this pop up is set.

```
function setItemID() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("ArquivoItens");
  var NovoItemSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Novo Item');

  var drang = sheet.getRange(1, 1, sheet.getLastRow(), 2);
  var ids = drang.getValues();
  var biggest = 0;

 //iterates through the list of ID's
  for(var i = 0; i < ids.length; i++){
    var id = ids[i][0];
    if(id > biggest){
      biggest = id;
    }
  }
  //although it is specified above that this is on Novo Item sheet, the pop up below keeps going off when I'm on EditarItem
  var selectedCell = NovoItemSheet.getRange("W4");

  for (var j = 1; j < ids.length; j++) {
    var itemName = ids[j][1];
    if (selectedCell.getValue() == itemName){
      Browser.msgBox('Já existe um item com este nome!')
      return;
    }
  }
```

Any helps as to why this is going on is appreciated.

Cheers,
Antonio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### When you edit any cell on any sheet, you trigger `onEdit` and run the function

- If the condition `selectedCell.getValue() == itemName` is fulfilled - you will get the alert message, no matter either you just created a duplicate product name or it already existed before.
- In order to avid this issue, you need to specify which kind of edit shall trigger the function.
- This is something you can do with e.g. by checking which sheet (and if necessary - also which range) has been edited.

Sample:

```
function setItemID() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var activeSheetName = ss.getActiveSheet().getName();
  if(activeSheetName == 'Novo Item'){
    // carry out the rest of the function
    ...
  }
}
```

Comment: Still kind of lost concept wise, but I'll get there! Danke!